# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'eav_attribute_option.option_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: magento-1.7

I am creating custom module in magento and using below query for fetching data from two table :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('citycountry/citycountry')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join('eav_attribute_option_value', 
  'eav_attribute_option.option_id=eav_attribute_option_value.option_id',
   array('value'));
```

than getting error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'eav_attribute_option.option_id' in 'on clause'
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Have you actually read the message? You're referring to a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: yes I read but column exist in table - eav_attribute_option.

Answer (score 0):

One thing could simply be that you're connecting to the wrong database, but I assume you're not.

A small 'gotcha' in Magento is that it makes use of Zend Framework (up to some point). Zend has this 'feature' where it caches the scheme of your database. Even when you have caching disabled in Magento, Zend still caches this (this is way you'll always have some files in your `var/cache`-folder even when all caches are off).

One thing you must always do when you're manually altering the database is to simply remove the entire cache-folder (`rm var/cache`). This could possibly fix your problem.

However, it's still strange since `eav_attribute_option` should come with a default install but I hope this helps you a bit.